# Can I get canActivate return value on Angular component?

Tags: angular, authentication

I'm guarding some of my component with AuthGuard, and some are not. Which is, it can be accessed although the user not logged in yet.

On that component, I want to show some difference on the UI between the logged in user and not logged in user. For example, the logged in user will be shown "Logout" menu in the sidebar, while not logged in user will be shown "Login" menu. So I need to get the canActivate value (or the status whether the user has logged in or not) on my component.

And this is my AuthGuard file :

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    ) { }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
    if (currentUser) {
        // check if route is restricted by role
        if (route.data.roles && route.data.roles.indexOf(currentUser.role) === -1) {
            // role not authorised so redirect to home page
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
            return false;
        }

        // authorised so return true
        return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    return false;
   }
}
```

I'm searching and asking to some sources and they said it can't be done. But probably you can tell the alternate way to do that

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions would be to create a service with method which would define user is authenticated or not and to use this method in AuthGuard and any components